# Slide android fragment using other view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-overscoll

i have 2 fragments, and I need to scroll this fragments up and down by selecting and dragging some small view(not selecting any place in fragment, only if I drag this veiw). Similary, i have an OverScroll on first fragment, which scrolls photos with animation. I tried using VerticalViewPager for it, but it unsuitable for this task, because it conflicts with overscroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `VerticalViewPager`, but override `onInterceptTouchEvent` and define a "hotspot" that will trigger the fragment flip. As an example to get you started, I've overridden `onInterceptTouchEvent`in a custom `ViewPager` such that edge swipes still "flip" the fragments (horizontally, in my case), but that interior swipes still get passed onto the `ViewFlipper` views inside the fragments

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            int screenW = getWidth();
            int screenH = getHeight();
            int screenWReducer = Math.round(screenW*0.5f);

            Rect rect = new Rect(
                    0 + screenWReducer,
                    0,
                    screenW - screenWReducer,
                    screenH
                    );

            if (rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {

                return false;//Don't intercept. Left ViewFlippers get touch.

            }

            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event); //Edges still allow page swiping.

}
```